# Spring bean injection from xml error : expected single matching bean but found

Tags: spring, code-injection

We are using Spring to create service beans for our tests.

I get error : Could not autowire field: private x.y.A expected single matching bean but found 2 [A,AA]

Code:

```
public class ATest {

    @Autowired
    private A a;
```

xml

```
<bean id="ida" class="x.y.A" />

<bean id="idaa" class="x.y.AA" />
```

Where:

```
AA.java  

class AA extends A { ... }
```

Cs

Comment: Are you sure it's not AA that extends A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("idaa")
private A a;
```

check the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html)

Comment: If `A` extends `AA`, then what you are proposing would fail since `idaa` is a bean of type `AA`, not of type `A`.

Comment: I got this from the error "expected single matching bean but found 2" , that happens when autowiring find two or more possible beans to wire for a property, so it cannot decide, @Qualifier helps you to indicate which bean you want to wire, I used here 'idaa' as an example, but if you need 'ida' , well just use it